# Как правильно: лосинный/лосиный стейк?

Tags: орфография

Правильно я думаю, что надо писать *лосиная шкура, лосиный мех, лосиная голова, лосиный рог, лосиное мясо* (от слова *лось*), но *лосинный стейк, лосинная котлета, лосинная колбаска* (от слова *лосина*)?

Comment: про мясо говорят лосятина. Стейк из лосятины, теоретически можно сказать стейк из лосины, что такое лосинный стейк? Свининная котлета?